# Activity to next Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

[image]

I am showing content by accessing database using a cursor. Currently, I am accessing my content data by listview through intent. Now, I want don't want to go back my listview instead of that I would like to access next data by a next and prev button in the top bar.

I know how to use button action. Now, How can I increment the cursor value or how can I access the  next content. Do you give me any idea ? I tried but I didn't find the logic to implement that. Once again I repeat my question is `How can I increment the cursor value or how can I access the  next content?`

Comment: use `cursor.moveToNext()`

Comment: @Raghunandan Question updated. I didn't implement the navbar button yet. Just testing with simple button with click()

Comment: I know cursor.movenext() increment the cursor number. But, I think cursor.movenext() is not my soultion or I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can fetched en-tired data from database via `Cursor`. But as per logic dependent how much to show via `Next` and `Previous` click event. You can store `lastFetchedRow` no. globally and moves your `Cursor` to that position accordingly to `Next` and `Previous` click events.

Here i showed a snippet to achieve `Next` click events which can put inside your `onClickListener` of `Next` button.

Assumed you have to fetched ten rows at a time. `lastFetchedRow` store row no which is been last fetched. `moveToPostion(integer)` moves cursor to that position. And Loops till where you want the data.

```
int i=0,lastFetchedRow;
Cursor cursor = db.query(....);
if (cursor != null)
 {
    while(i!=10)
    { 
       if(i=0)
        {
           cursor.moveToPosition(lastFetchedRow) 
        }
    cursor.moveToNext();
    //Save your data in some getter & setter object
     } 
 }
 lastFetchedTow = cursor.getPosition();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that should be taken into consideration.

1. You might want to change your UI architecture to an `Activity` -> `Fragment` setup. In the `Activity` you would do your `Cursor` alterations (next, previous) and display the content in a `Fragment` attached to that activity. This would prevent having to rerun the query for every page displayed.
2. Alternatively, you can use a `ViewPager` to better achieve what you are trying to do while still only running the query once. In your `PagerAdapter` for the `ViewPager` you would alter your cursors position.

Comment: As my project specification, I can't use ViewPager. Thanks for the info.

Comment: What about fragments?

Answer (score 0):

solution for what you want to trying:

first you get index of Listview at which you click
and this will be index of your table right ??

now second thing

1 putextra and getextra method through you can get value of that index.. make it global

2 make method for finding next and previous index by passing current index

on click event of previous or next button call that function and 
query like this:

String q= "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id='" + vg;

Cursor  cursor = database.rawQuery(query,null);

so you get next or previous row of table 
and show data..

dont forget to replace index with newly find index..